# Guice Binding API by Example

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

I have read several articles and tutorials on Guice (3.0), and now have a few lingering questions before I can "tie it all together".

```
// 1. Binds via public, no-arg "ServiceImpl()" ctor?
bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class);

// 2. Every client-side request for a Service instance returns the same
//    ServiceImpl instance?
ServiceImpl impl = new ServiceImpl(...);
bind(Service.class).toInstance(impl);

// 3. Every client-side request for a Service instance returns the same
//    SINGLETON ServiceImpl instance?
ServiceImpl impl = new ServiceImpl(...);
bind(Service.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON).toInstance(impl);

// 4. Should this be a call too bindConstant() instead of toInstance()
//    instead? If so, how/why?
Integer timeout = 1000 * 60;   // 60 seconds
bind(Integer.class).named(Names.named("TIMEOUT")).toInstance(timeout);
```

So my questions, as implied by the code snippet above:

1. When using `to(...)`, I assume the public no-arg ctor is used, and a new instance is returned every time?
2. Per #2 above, is the same `impl` instance used for ever `Service.class` request, or is a new one returned?
3. Same as #3 above, but now with `Scopes.SINGLETON` specified.
4. Is the above code OK or should I be using `bindConstant()`? If so, how/why?
5. Under what circumstances should I be using so-called [**provider methods**](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectingProviders)? I *sort of* understand the example on that page, but am now choking when it comes to finding a real-world use case for them in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Either the public no-argument constructor is used, or an @Inject-annotated constructor (that would be recommended).  A new instance is returned every time, unless you specify a scope on ServiceImpl (either by a later `bind(ServiceImpl.class).in(...)` line or an `@Singleton` annotation on `ServiceImpl`.
2. In this case, the same `impl` instance is used for every injection of `Service`
3. That is a compile error, for good reason -- you can't specify a scope on a `toInstance` binding.
4. `bindConstant()` should be used for things like configuration parameters that are primitive or String types.  For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165506/guice-difference-between-binderbindconstant-and-binderbind-toinstance).
5. `@Provides` methods are simply a shorter way of writing `Provider<>`s. If you don't have a need for them, don't use them. They should generally be used if creating an object is more complicated than a simple constructor call.

Comment: Thanks @Tavian Barnes (+1) - 1 followup question for you: regarding #5 (Provider methods), I'm still not understanding a proper use case for them. Say I have a `RabbitMQConnection` class that can only be properly configured by calling its no-arg ctor and then setting a bunch of fields with various `setXXX(...)` calls. Why can't I just create this `RabbitMQConnection` instance and then use `toInstance()`? What benefit does a provider or `@Provides` method give me over `bind(RabbitMQConnection.class).toInstance(myRabbitMQConn)`?

Comment: One main benefit would be lazy instantiation in `Stage.DEVELOPMENT`. Another benefit is that `toInstance` can't support non-singleton scopes.

Comment: @IAmYourFaja injecting `Providers` allows you to get multiple instances of Guice created classes (by calling `get` repeatedly). It will also allow you to mix scopes (ie getting session or request scoped objects inside a servlet)