# Binding a 2-D array in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

I have to create an object of `ModelWeights` using Guice Dependency injection. How can I bind a `double[][]` array using Guice dependency injection during runtime?

```
public class MW {

    private double[][] weights;
    private LogConditionalObjectiveFunction objectiveFunction;

    @Inject
    public MW(double[][] weights, LogConditionalObjectiveFunction func)
    {
        this.weights = weights;
        this.objectiveFunction = func;
    }

    public double[][] getWeights()
    {
        return this.weights;
    }

    public LogConditionalObjectiveFunction getObjectiveFunction()
    {
        return this.objectiveFunction;
    }
}
```

I got this while trying several approaches:

```
1) No implementation for double[][] was bound.
  while locating double[][]
    for parameter 0 at com.data.MW.<init>(MW.java:13)
  while locating com.data.MW
    for parameter 0 at com.predictor.impl.MEP.<init>(MEP.java:50)
  at     com.ServletDependencyInjector$1.configureServlets(ServletDependencyInjector.java:72)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Guice constants binding

```
@Inject
public ModelWeights(@Named("MyMatrix") double[][] weights, LogConditionalObjectiveFunction func) {
        this.weights = weights;
        this.objectiveFunction = func;
}
```

And in your Guice setup code

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
   bind(double[][].class).annotatedWith(Names.named("MyMatrix")).toInstance(MY_MATRIX); 
}
```

Comment: Hrm?  I see no overload for `double[][]` [here](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/binder/ConstantBindingBuilder.java).  Just do `bind(double[][].class).toInstance(MY_MATRIX)`

Comment: @TavianBarnes I guess the OP is more interested at binding *constants* and not bind of an instance per se, (I've mentioned bindConstant usage of some static, possibly final variable). please also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165506/guice-difference-between-binderbindconstant-and-binderbind-toinstance

Comment: Regardless of any of that, your code won't compile.  You can only use `bindConstant()` with primitives, `String`s, `Class<?>`s and `enum`s.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Regarding the compilation, thx for pointing out, I've edited my answer (I should've place a disclaimer I coded from my head w/o compiling it actually). Regarding "just do bind(double[][].class).toInstance(MY_MATRIX)" , this will inject *ANY* double matrix (if it will appear in the code) to the instance, this could lead to troubles hence annotations which restricts the injection scope (so to speak) is better